# PHP: Test for string of text inside html tags from file_get_contents string

Tags: php, html

I need to perform a series of tests on a url. The first test is a word count, I have that working perfectly and the code is below:

```
if (isset($_GET[article_url])){
    $title = 'This is an example title';
    $str = @file_get_contents($_GET[article_url]);
    $test1 = str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($str)));
    if($test1 === FALSE) { $test = '0'; }
    if ($test1 > '550') {
        echo '<div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="color:green"></i> This article has '.$test1.' words.';
    } else {
        echo '<div><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" style="color:red"></i> This article has '.$test1.' words. You are required to have a minimum of 500 words.';
    }       
}
```

Next I need to get all h1 and h2 tags from $str and test them to see if any contain the text $title and echo yes if so and no if not. I am not really sure how to go about doing this.

I am looking for a pure php means of doing this without installing php libraries or third party functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below code.

```
if (isset($_GET[article_url])){
    $title = 'This is an example title';
    $str = @file_get_contents($_GET[article_url]);

    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($str);

    $tags = array ('h1', 'h2');
    $texts = array ();
    foreach($tags as $tag)
    {
      //Fetch all the tags with text from the dom matched with passed tags
      $elementList = $document->getElementsByTagName($tag);
      foreach($elementList as $element)
      {
         //Store text in array from dom for tags
         $texts[] = strtolower($element->textContent);
      }
    }
    //Check passed title is inside texts array or not using php
    if(in_array(strtolower($title),$texts)){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this spits out countless Dom errors such as Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 146 It also always returns no, even when it should return yes.

Comment: Can you please place print_r($texts) before if condition and check the output.

Comment: the output looks like this: Array ( [h1] => Array ( [0] => the startup business success plan ) [h2] => Array ( [0] => about us [1] => your board [2] => the services [3] => membership fees [4] => partners [5] => startmeeting® [6] => entrepreneur power hour [7] => the downliner [8] => adsactly hits [9] => contact us ) ) no. And no is output even if I use the text "contact us".

Comment: I have tried with rtrim ltrim, trim all just return false 100% of the time.

Comment: There character encoding issue when getting string using file_get_content. When there are special charters in a string then string doesn't match correctly and it very strange. To sort it out I have tried strip_tags,html_entity_decode,htmlspecialcharacters_decode.

Comment: I got it sorted.... I had to change the foreach to  $texts[$element->tagName] = strtolower($element->textContent);

Comment: Any suggestion on suppressing the warnings